# Use Sql Server FileStream in Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

In a silverlight applicaiton i use entity framework as Data Access Layer. I want to use FileStream Capability in Silverlight applicaiton , but entity framework does not support this.how can i implement this with or without entity framework in silverlight application?!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some excellent pointers on using SQL FILESTREAM and Silverlight + RIA Services in Chris Rouw's blog:

[Storing Files in SQL Server using WCF RIA Services and Silverlight - Part 1](http://blog.farreachinc.com/2011/06/07/storing-files-in-sql-server-using-wcf-ria-services-and-silverlight-part-1/)

[Storing Files in SQL Server using WCF RIA Services and Silverlight - Part 2](http://blog.farreachinc.com/2011/06/15/storing-files-in-sql-server-using-wcf-ria-services-and-silverlight-part-2-2/)

Part three available as well...

Answer (score 1):

[Pretty good answer to the question here](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/234175/575917.aspx).

Basically, you use an HTTP handler in ASP.Net to return the file over HTTP so Silverlight can download it and serve it up to the client. It is pretty hard to give you much more detail than this since your question is pretty vague.